# For loop makes ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException... sometimes?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am using a for loop to iterate through the keyset of a ConcurrentHashMap.  However, sometimes (unpredictably) it crashes with ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.  Here is the code I am using:

```
net_keys = MonitorService.net_list.keySet().toArray(net_keys); 
net_count = net_keys.length;

for (net_count_iterator = 0; net_count_iterator < net_count; net_count_iterator++) {
    ap_iterator = MonitorService.net_list.get(net_keys[net_count_iterator]);
    if (ap_iterator.ssid.contains(search_ssid)) {
        aps_temp.add(ap_iterator);
    }
}
```

net_keys is a String[], ap_iterator is a temporary object, net_count is an int, and MonitorService.net_list is a ConcurrentHashMap.  net_list holds potentially thousands of key/value pairs that are being added to (but never removed from) by a different thread while this iteration is taking place, so my problem could be related to concurrency.  I am specifically avoiding using an enhanced for loop to avoid object allocation (specifically, the time it takes for the garbage collector to clean them up).  My question to the experts is: how can it be that net_keys.length is greater than the array elements in net_keys?  What can I do to correct this issue?  Thank you for your insight.

Comment: `I am specifically avoiding using an enhanced for loop to avoid object allocation` Enhanced for loop iterates over the objects that already exist, it does not create anything new except for an `Iterator`. And you are duplicating the `net_keys` array. Anyway, if you do not tell which line launches the exception, is it hard to tell.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the exception is thrown by `net_list.get`, not `net_keys[net_count_iterator]`. I'd try splitting in two your first line in the loop, and writing in console to confirm where is the problem. Something like.-

```
int key = net_keys[net_count_iterator];
System.out.println("*** Got key " + key);
ap_iterator = MonitorService.net_list.get(key);
System.out.println("*** Got iterator " + ap_iterator);
```

PS: consider using *camelCase* for your variable names, it's more *java friendly* :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the code below? I just add `- 1` in the for loop.

```
net_keys = MonitorService.net_list.keySet().toArray(net_keys); 
net_count = net_keys.length;

for (net_count_iterator = 0; net_count_iterator <= net_count - 1; net_count_iterator++) {
    ap_iterator = MonitorService.net_list.get(net_keys[net_count_iterator]);
    if (ap_iterator.ssid.contains(search_ssid)) {
        aps_temp.add(ap_iterator);
    }
}
```